# Where can I find the list of companies in US that have defaulted

Tags: equities, finance

I am trying to find a list of US companies that have defaulted in the recent past .Any link for this?

Comment: Defaulted like missed a payment on a loan for a few months, or Chapter 11? 8-K SEC for public companies comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you tagged your question equities. Do you mean that you don't care for corporation that don't have publicly traded equity, but have defaulted on their debt?

A good start would be the [Credit Derivatives Determinations Committees](https://www.cdsdeterminationscommittees.org/) (spun off from former ISDA Credit Derivatives Determinations Committee in 2018). Look for North American corporate events like "Has a Bankruptcy Credit Event occurred with respect to Noble Corporation?" or "Has a Bankruptcy Credit Event occurred with respect to ENSCO International Incorporated?"